# How to force Spotlight to import existing index instead of rebuilding (network share)?

Tags: macos, spotlight, nas, afp, indexing

I am having trouble to make Spotlight permanently work for network drives on both Sierra and High Sierra.

I have a NAS (WD MyCloud, running some proprietary linux, kinda busybox) on my local network. I connect to it using AFP protocol. The given shares mounted somewhere in my home folder `~/path-to-share`. I can enable Spotlight search by manually starting indexing the volume.

```
sudo mkdir /private/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes/
mdutil -i on ~/path_to_mount
```

The first line is needed since Sierra, without that, you will always get `Indexing disabled.` in the terminal (this is a fix a lot of people looking for). This will start mdworker, and the indexing starts. After it finishes Spotlight works as it supposed, temporarily.  **BUT once you unmount the share and mount it (the same way) again Spotlight stops finding anything within it.**

During indexing a local database is built under `/private/var/db/Spotlight-V100/Volumes/afp%3A`. If you take look at the content of this folder, one can find further subfolders name according to user@server_name nomenclature. This would suggest, that it would recognize the server. Manually rebuilding the index with `mdutil -i on E ~/path_to_mount` "restarts" proper Spotlight functioning, but it can take hours with a considerably large network share, which is unmounted automatically with one single WiFi network change (I am using a portable computer).

**So the question would be how can you make Spotlight find/read/use the already existing  - not corrupted - index database.**

I have tried different mounting methods, same result: Finder, command line (`mount -w -o nosuid -o nodev -t afp afp://server_name/share_name ~/path_to_mount`). I have also tried to mount to the default `/Volumes/` path, the same result. I can not reload to associated deamon `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist` since it is protected by SIP. I have tried everything with SMB sharing also.

Interestingly this problem seems to annoy only a handful of people, I could only find one similar question ([How to force spotlight to reimport index](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234094/how-to-force-spotlight-to-reimport-index)), but dozens and dozens of "How to rebuild Spotlight index". Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: wondering if you ever solved this and just forgot to come back and answer your own question?